# TabBarController behind the scenes and correct approach for code behind

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller

Just imagine( as case) that i have ***TabBarController*** as root and several **ViewControllers** that are linked to this TabBarController( via **Storyboard(!)** that is important step,i mean programmatically it's something other).

[image: TabBarController]

And its works without any **code behind** on **TabBarController** class!

So i'm interested in right approach, how can i **Inistiate** Viewcontrollers inside **TabBarController** on right way!?
Or it's isn't necessary and **OS** will do it for me , because at current moment, i can do something like this :

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {   //No Init for VC that are inside linked to TabBAr
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            //Find all viewcontrollers that are linked in storyboard
            foreach (var Item in ViewControllers)
            {
                Item.TabBarItem.Image = 
                UIImage.FromBundle("RandomImg");
                //Change title for all VC to "Main"
                Item.TabBarItem.Title = "Main";
                break;
            }
}
```

What if i will do initialization of **ViewControllers** inside **TabBarController** constructor.
What will be happened on behind the scenes? How the system will recognize my init of VC,or it's doesn't matter and thats will be an redundant action, because technique via storyboard anyway creates **ViewControllers** without any initialization on **code behind**!?

How to handle/customize correctly **ViewControllers** that are inside of  TabBarController?(e.g. select another VC at beginning, change buttons on **TabBar** and etc)

I would like to take all answers on all my questions and if it possible, need an live example/article that explains more advanced about this stuff. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this solves your doubt but you can read this -: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-exploring-tab-bar-controller--cms-25470

Comment: @TusharSharma thanks for the reply, ill do an investigation in this article ;).